# jqvmap - regionclick method not firing unless called in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the JQVMap plugin (http://jqvmap.com/) to create a map.  The plugin has a method called onRegionClick that lets you call a function if a region on the map is selected.

I'm loading the map dynamically using a function called loadSlide, but for some reason the onRegionClick method isn't being called, nor is the bind method I've called afterward.  Strangely, if I load that bind method into my browser console after the page has loaded, it works great.

I'm totally happy to provide more code/context if necessary, but I'm at my wit's end with this.  Anyone familiar with this plugin and have experience with this problem?  Thanks!

Pertinent code below:

```
function loadSlide(url,data) {
data.slide_id = $('#slide-data input#slide_id').val();
$.getJSON(url, data, function(response) {
    $('#slide-content').replaceWith(response.html);

        if ( $("#vmap").length > 0 ) {

              $('#vmap').vectorMap({
                map: 'usa_en',
                backgroundColor: null,
                color: '#6a1912',
                hoverColor: '#fdb33f',
                selectedColor: '#fdb33f',
                enableZoom: true,
                showTooltip: true,
                onRegionClick: function(event, code, region) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('input[type=hidden]#state-click').val(code.toUpperCase());
                    console.log($('input[type=hidden]#state-click').val());
                }
            });

            $('#vmap').bind('regionClick.jqvmap', function(event, code, region) {
                $('input[type=hidden]#state-click').val(code.toUpperCase());
                console.log($('input[type=hidden]#state-click').val());
            });

            setClickHandlers();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'll bet the issue was the Console.log line?

Comment: This might be a really naive statement, but I didn't know that console.log could affect whether a function fires or not.

Comment: Yep - The console object is not defined in IE >8 or in FF unless Firebug is open.  In Chrome it's always defined.

One way to handle it is to define it if it is not defined:if(!window.console) console = {log: function() {}};